# How can I use custom method in UseEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

How can I use custom method in useEffect??
If I create many components and they use same fetch function, Shoud I declare fetch function in every component's effect?? The function does same work??

As far as I know, If I want to use component's state in useEffect, I should declare and call that function in useEffect likes example 1.

But I want to declare the function other js file. Because it was called other components.

According to Dan Abramov (https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), If I want to move function, I must use useCallback method.
But I didn't understand well. Please give me any advice this issue.

```
1. Component.js
const Component = () => {
    const [id,setId] = useState(0);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`url/${id}`).then(res => dispatch({type: success, payload: res}))
    },[id])
}

2. Component.js 
const Component = () => {
    const [id, setId] = useState(0);

    useEffect(()=> {
        callApi(id)
    },[id])
}

Api.js
const callApi = (id) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return fetch(`url/${id}`).then(res => dispatch({type:success, payload:res})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shoud I declare fetch function in every component's effect?

Extract a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), `useFetch()`, with the same fetch functionality.

```
// custom hook
const useFetch = (id) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(
      () => {
        async function fetchData() {
          const res = await fetch(`url/${id})
          setData(res);
        }
        fetchData();
      }, [id] // id as dependency
    )

    return data;
}

// sample component using custom hook
const Component = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const data = useFetch(props.id); // use custom hook

    useEffect(
      () => {
        if (data) {
          dispatch({type: success, payload: data});
        }
      }, [data] // dispatch every time data changes
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think creating cumtom hook. But I have a question 

When the Component give parameter(id) to useFetch and the id is component's state,

How to re-run useFetch if id is changed? Shouldn't useFetch be in useEffect??

Like this : useEffect(()=>useFetch(id),[id]) ?? 

Is it OK because saved on data and useEffect deps has data??

Comment: See [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). `useFetch` uses `useEffect` which has `id` as dependency. So the fetch will re-run every time `id` changes then return the new data. If not, it will just return the old data.

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple of your components perform the same action within useEffect, you can extract out the code into a custom hook and use it in all the components

useFetch.js

```
export const useFetch = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`url/${id}).then(res => dispatch({type: success, payload: res}))
    },[id])
}
```

Now in the component you can write

```
const Component = () => {
    const [id, setId] = useState(0);
    useFetch(id);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.
But I have a question. 
If id will be changed by any events, Should I move useFetch in useEffect?? 

useEffect(()=>useFetch(id),[id]); ??

Comment: No you don't need to do that, since whenever id changes useFetch will be called with the new id on updated render and useEffect inside it will run

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I have been solved all my question! I must will be good at create custom hook! Thank you!